# не корректная работа метода val() jquery

Tags: jquery

В интернет магазине есть кнопки + и - для указания количества товаров, добавляемых в корзину. между ними инпут, в котором собственно это количество и указывается. Т.е. - ___ +

html разметка такая

```
 <div class = "tbcs">
                                                    <div class="order__minus order__minus--large" tabindex="2" style="font-weight:100; margin: 0;">
                                                        <span>-</span>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="order__count order__count--large">
                                                        <span>
                                                            <input id="product_<?=$product->id?>" type="number" value="<?=$item['count'][$product->id]['count']?>" class="handle-quantity" style="width: 50px; text-align: center; outline: none; border: none; font-weight:100; font-size: 14px;">
                                                                <div class="hidden js_qant"
                                                                   <?php if($use_aval):?>data-available='<?= $product->available; ?>'<?php endif;?> 
                                                                    data-min_quantity='<?= $product->min_quantity > 0 ? $product->min_quantity : $product->step_quantity; ?>'
                                                                    data-step_quantity='<?= $product->step_quantity; ?>'
                                                                  ></div>
                                                        </span>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="order__plus order__plus--large" tabindex="1" style="font-weight:100; margin: 0;">
                                                        <span>+</span>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
```

Значение в инпуте может изменяться как вручную, прямым набором количества в инпуте, так и кликаньем на + и -. При изменении количества мне надо показать изменившуюся сумму по товару, которая полетит в корзину. Затык произошёл тогда, когда я стал изменять значение в инпуте посредством кликов на + и -. Код такой

```
// изменение суммы по товару при ручном изменении кол-ва
$(".handle-quantity").on('input', function(){
    parent = $(this).closest(".t812__pricelist-item");
    count = $(this).val();
    price = parent.find(".prod_price").text();
    prodSum = (count * price).toFixed(2);
    parent.find(".sum").text(prodSum);
});

$(".order__minus").on('click', function(){
    changeSum($(this));
});
$(".order__plus").on('click', function(){
    changeSum($(this));
});

// изменение суммы по товару при кликах на + и -
function changeSum(data){
    parent = $(data).closest(".t812__pricelist-item");
    id = parent.attr('id');
    count = parent.find("#product_"+id).val(); <!---- вот тут
    price = parent.find(".prod_price").text();
    prodSum = (count * price).toFixed(2);
    parent.find(".sum").text(prodSum);
}
```

Когда я вручную изменяю кол-во, то метод input() показывает верное значение - а именно значение в инпуте, которое получилось ПОСЛЕ его изменения. Если я кликаю на + и -, то метод val() мне почему-то отдаёт значение которое было ДО изменения инпута, что соответственно приводит к ошибке расчёта окончательной суммы. Везде в документации написано, что val() отдаёт текущее значение инпута, а у меня он срабатывает не так. Пожалуйста, объясните почему так.

Comment: Эээм... а в каком месте тут происходит изменение значения при клике? Это в другом месте прописано или просто убрали из примера?) К слову, `parent.find("#product_"+id).val();` можно заменить просто на `$("#product_"+id).val();` ... на странице все равно не должно быть два одинаковых id)

Comment: я думал, что это происходит при событии click, но как подсказали ниже, оно почему-то не происходит. Пока не пойму почему.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При нажатии кнопок, Вы не меняете значение `count` в параметрах. 
В связи с этим и значение берётся текущее(До изменения)
Попробуйте таким образом(Передавать в функцию либо дополнительное значение для плюса и минуса, или просто знак):

```
    $(".handle-quantity").on('input', function(){
        parent = $(this).closest(".t812__pricelist-item");
        count = $(this).val();
        price = parent.find(".prod_price").text();
        prodSum = (count * price).toFixed(2);
        parent.find(".sum").text(prodSum);
    });

    $(".order__minus").on('click', function(){
        changeSum($(this));
    });
    $(".order__plus").on('click', function(){
        changeSum($(this));
    });

    // изменение суммы по товару при кликах на + и -
    function changeSum(data){
        let znak = Number( $(data).children().eq(0).text() + "1" );
        let step = $('.hidden.js_qant').data('step_quantity'); // Получить шаг
        let min = $('.hidden.js_qant').data('min_quantity'); // Получить минимальное значение
        parent = $(data).closest(".t812__pricelist-item");
        id = parent.attr('id');
        count = +parent.find("#product_"+id).val();
        count += znak * step;
        price = parent.find(".prod_price").text();
        prodSum = (count * price).toFixed(2);
        parent.find(".sum").text(prodSum);
    }
```

Если Вы хотите избавиться от строк кода:

```
    $(".order__minus").on('click', function(){
        changeSum($(this));
    });
    $(".order__plus").on('click', function(){
        changeSum($(this));
    });
```

То Вы можете просто вызывать функцию в самих `div`:

```
<div class="order__minus order__minus--large" tabindex="2" style="font-weight:100; margin: 0;" onclick="changeSum(this)"><span>-</span></div>
<div class="order__plus order__plus--large" tabindex="1" style="font-weight:100; margin: 0;" onclick="changeSum(this)"><span>+</span></div>
```

Comment: передача знака была как идея, но я отнёсся к ней критически, как к любому костылю. В добавок к этому, изменение значения через + и - может быть не на 1, а на упаковку, например, 12, 24, 36... единиц. И пригородить костыль с передачей кратности к костылю со знаком мне не хотелось бы. Поэтому я бы хотел получить ответ, который скорее всего будет связан с изменением кода в этой части: "$(".order__minus").on('click'", т.е. вешать обработчик не на событие click, а на что-то другое

Comment: @Oughtem Тогда Вам необходимо дополнить Ваш вопрос, что Вы хотите получить и шаг прибавления и знак и т.д. Добавил в ответ. (Получаем знак через `children` указанный в `span`, получаем минимальное количество товара через атрибут `data` и через него получаем шаг товаров.)

Comment: Denis640Kb, судя по вашей репутации, я понимаю, что дурного вы не посоветуете, но всё же... мне одному кажется, что это костыли? Не логичнее ли попытаться вызвать работу функции не  $(".order__minus").on('click', function(){ , а чем-то другим, что осуществляло бы изменение значения count в параметрах? Мне кажется, грамотнее было бы именно так...

Comment: `let sign = Number( $(data).children().eq(0).text() + "1" ); count += sign * step;` — sign получается или 1, или -1 )

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME Да, Вы правы. Так гораздо лучше. Спасибо за дельное замечание. Добавил в ответ, если Вы не против.

Comment: @Oughtem Вы же хотите использовать кнопки для пересчёта суммы, верно? В этом случае Вам при любом раскладе необходимо вызывать их обработку. Или Вы можете в сам `div` добавить вызов функции через `onclick="changeSum(this)"`

Comment: Да, всё работает, единственное, что вот эти переменные надо вычислять так:
    let step = parent.find('.hidden.js_qant').data('step_quantity');
    let min = parent.find('.hidden.js_qant').data('min_quantity');
Спасибо!

Comment: Ещё момент. А если мы не имеем step? например тогда, когда юзер вводит данные не через + и -, а вручную в инпут и они там автоматически корректируются согласно пакетированию, то как в таком случае выцепить значение ПОСЛЕ такого корректирования?

Comment: @Oughtem Не понял Вашего вопроса. При вводе значения вручную в поле - у Вас рассчитывается сумма отдельно и записываются в поле.

Comment: создал новый вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1100774/получение-значений-из-формы-до-и-после-их-изменения-js