# получение значений из формы до и после их изменения, js

Tags: javascript

в интерент-магазине есть + и - для добавления товара в корзину и между ними есть input в который вручную можно ввести данные, не прибегая к + или -. У товара есть пакетирование и вручную ввести можно только согласно нему. Так, к примеру, если пакетирование = 12, а юзер ввёл "20", то ему исправит на 24.

Есть некое недопонимание в том как JS извлекает данные из формы. Недопонимание связано с тем, то я могу понять истинное значение переменной. Если я вывожу её в console.log(), то получаю значение ДО редактирования инпута, но там же в инструменте Watch я получаю значение ПОСЛЕ редактирования. Прикреплю скриншот и куски кода, чтоб стало понятно.

Скриншот, на котором видна суть вопроса: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И собственно код:
1. catalog-component.js содержит логику определения количества товара, если оно указано не кратно пакетированию.

```
var CatalogComponent = {
    productPage: false,
    count: 0,

    init: function() {

        var self = this;
        var $products = $('body');

        $products.on('keyup', '.handle-quantity', function() {
            self.setCount($(this));
        });


    },

    changeCount: function($input, plus) {
        var count = parseInt($input.val());
        var maxCount = $input.parent().find('div.hidden').data('available')?$input.parent().find('div.hidden').data('available'):9999999;
        var minCount = $input.parent().find('div.hidden').data('min_quantity');
        var stepCount = $input.parent().find('div.hidden').data('step_quantity'); 

        if (plus) {
            if ((count + stepCount ) <= maxCount) {
                count+=stepCount;
            }else{
                count = maxCount;
            }
        } else {
            if(count == maxCount){
                if((count - minCount) % stepCount != 0 ){           
                    count -= minCount;
                    if(count<stepCount){
                        count = stepCount;
                    }
                    count = Math.ceil(count/stepCount)*stepCount;
                    if((count+minCount)<minCount){
                        count = minCount;
                    }else{          
                        if((count+minCount)>maxCount){
                            count = maxCount-minCount;
                            count = Math.floor(count/stepCount)*stepCount;                  
                        }
                        count +=minCount;
                    }
                }
                if(count == maxCount){
                    count-=stepCount;
                }               
            }else{
                if ((count - stepCount) >= minCount) {
                    count-=stepCount;
                }else{
                    count = minCount;
                }
            }
        }
        this.count = parseInt(count);
        this.setCount($input, count);
    },
 setCount: function($input, count) {

    var maxCount = $input.parent().find('div.hidden').data('available')?$input.parent().find('div.hidden').data('available'): ($input.parent().find('div.hidden').data('min_quantity')) * 10000;
    var minCount = $input.parent().find('div.hidden').data('min_quantity');
    var stepCount = $input.parent().find('div.hidden').data('step_quantity');

    if (count === undefined) {
        count = $input.val();
    }
    if (count === '') {
        return ;
    }

    if (!$.isNumeric(count)) {
        count = minCount;
    }

    if (count > maxCount) {
        count = maxCount;
    } else if (count === 0) {
        count = minCount;
    }


    count = parseInt(count);        
    if((count - minCount) % stepCount != 0 && count != maxCount){           
        count -= minCount;
        if(count<stepCount){
            count = stepCount;
        }
        count = Math.ceil(count/stepCount)*stepCount;
        if((count+minCount)<minCount){
            count = minCount;
        }else{          
            if((count+minCount)>maxCount){
                count = maxCount-minCount;
                count = Math.floor(count/stepCount)*stepCount;                  
            }
            count +=minCount;
        }
    }


    $input.val(parseInt(count));
},

};
```

Тут после того, как логика отработала я запихиваю окончательное значение в свойство объекта `this.count = parseInt(count);`

Потом, следующим кодом я достаю это свойство, надеясь его использовать

```
function getCnt(){
    return CatalogComponent.count;
}

// изменение сумм при ручном изменении кол-ва
$(".handle-quantity").on('input', function(){
    let parent = $(this).closest(".t812__pricelist-item");
    let id = parent.attr('id');
    let count = $(this).val();
    let price = parent.find(".prod_price").text();
    let prodSum = Math.abs((count * price).toFixed(2));


    console.log(getCnt());    



    // изменение суммы по товару
    parent.find(".sum").text(prodSum);
    // изменение суммы корзины
    changeTotalSum($(this));
    //изменение кол-ва товара в базе
    var arr = {'id': id, 'count': count};
    changeSumInBd(arr);
});
```

Но в нём лежит значение инпута ДО его изменения. Это и продемонстрировано на скриншоте. Соответственно мой вопрос в там, как передать/получить значение ПОСЛЕ изменения инпута.

Ибо получается так, что вставить полученное значение в инпут можно:  `$input.val(parseInt(count));`, а использовать его для вычислений нельзя, т.к. получается старое значение.

---Пока писал вопрос, подумал, что у меня в 2 местах инициализируется реакция на изменения инпута. Может быть в этом вся соль.

Comment: А где функция `setCount()`?

Comment: добавил её в коде, но она по сути тут роли не играет.

Comment: @Oughtem Так же не указана функция `changeTotalSum`. Давайте попробуем подойти с другой стороны. Какая у Вас вообще задача стоит?

Comment: задача - исправить проблему. Проблема заключается в том, что при изменении кол-ва товара вручную в инпуте общая сумма по товару и соответственно общая сумма в корзине исчисляется исходя из того значения, которое юзер ввёл в инпут. А должно исчисляться исходя из того значения, которое возвращается из функции, корректирующей количество согласно пакетированию.

Comment: @Oughtem Тут много чего менять надо. Начиная от `keyup` и заканчивая вызовом самой функции.

Comment: Наличие ошибки само собой предполагает внесение изменений в код) если вы понимаете в чем суть - объясните, пожалуйста логику. Техническое исполнение я сделаю сам. Мне просто понять суть ошибки надо. Почему разные значения получаются?

Comment: @Oughtem Окей. В комментарий всё не поместиться - напишу в ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если идти по порядку разбора Вашего кода:
 1. Нигде не указаны вызовы следующих функций
a) `changeCount`
b) `changeTotalSum($(this));`(ну тут понятно почему)
с) `changeSumInBd(arr);` (Тут тоже)
По-этому пока временно убираем эти функции из кода. Вы их добавите в дальнейшем самостоятельно.
 2. В строке

```
$products.on('keyup', '.handle-quantity', function() {
            self.setCount($(this));
        });
```

Вы вызываете метод `keyup`, что будем менять значение в тот момент, когда клавиша отжата. 
Соответственно, если будут вводить двузначные и так далее цифры, то данные будут меняться, не давая до конца ввести свои данные. 
В данном случае лучше использовать метод потери фокуса поля - `blur`.
 3. В функция `setCount` ожидает от Вас передачи 2 параметров `function($input, count)`. 
Вы же передаёте в него один, используя вызов функции `self.setCount($(this));`
Понятно, что в дальнейшем Вы проверяете данный параметр на `undefined` - `if (count === undefined)`. Но в этом нет смысла, так как он всегда будет `undefined`, так как данные туда не передаются и переменная не имеет объявленного значения.
Либо передавайте туда значение в функции используя `self.setCount($(this), $(this).val());` либо по аналогии с функцией `changeCount` получайте этот параметр уже в самой функции. 
`var count = parseInt($input.val());`

4 Вы используете изменение поля ввода в самой функции `setCount` добавляя `$input.val(parseInt(count));`
 Так же прям там вы получаете необходимые Вам данные для расчёта, этом случае Вам необходимо тогда подкорректировать `$(".handle-quantity").on('input', function(){` 
(Там Вы получаете данные, которые могут отличаться от тех, которые Вы корректируете при вводе)
К примеру, Вам необходимо получать `count` не через `$(this).val();`, а через вызов самой функции `setCount` добавив в конец этой функции после вставки значения в поле `return count;`. Чтобы данные у Вас были одинаковые и по цене и по количеству.(Пример получения будет чуть ниже)

5 Вы сделали временную функцию для вызова `getCnt`, которая должна возвращать Вам `count`, но в данном случае у Вас не вызываются функции внутри, по-этому Вы всегда будете получать 0.
Изначально в функции `getCnt` нет смысла, так как Вы можете вызывать функции прямо из `CatalogComponent`.
В этом случае Вы уже получите значение, которое возвращаете в `return`:
`CatalogComponent.init()`
Соответственно, для получения значения в `count` в `$(".handle-quantity").on('input', function(){`
`let count = CatalogComponent.init();`

Так же Вам надо подкорректировать расчёты самой суммы, учитывая шаг товара. (Сейчас он работает не совсем корректно, менять не стал, мало ли чего-то не знаю в Вашем `html`).
Он всегда делает обработку в большую сторону

Но в целом должно выглядеть примерно так:

```js
    var CatalogComponent = {
        productPage: false,
        count: 0,

        init: function() {
            var self = this;
            var $products = $('body');
            $products.on('blur', '.handle-quantity', function() {
                self.setCount($(this), $(this).val());
            });
        },

        setCount: function($input, count) {
            var maxCount = $input.parent().find('div.hidden').data('available') ? $input.parent().find('div.hidden').data('available') : ($input.parent().find('div.hidden').data('min_quantity')) * 10000;
            var minCount = $input.parent().find('div.hidden').data('min_quantity');
            var stepCount = $input.parent().find('div.hidden').data('step_quantity');

            if (count === undefined) {
                count = $input.val();
            }
            if (count === '') {
                return;
            }
            if (!$.isNumeric(count)) {
                count = minCount;
            }
            if (count > maxCount) {
                count = maxCount;
            } else if (count === 0) {
                count = minCount;
            }

            count = parseInt(count);
            if ((count - minCount) % stepCount != 0 && count != maxCount) {
                count -= minCount;
                if (count < stepCount) {
                    count = stepCount;
                }
                count = Math.ceil(count / stepCount) * stepCount;
                if ((count + minCount) < minCount) {
                    count = minCount;
                } else {
                    if ((count + minCount) > maxCount) {
                        count = maxCount - minCount;
                        count = Math.floor(count / stepCount) * stepCount;
                    }
                    count += minCount;
                }
            }
            $input.val(parseInt(count));
            return count;
        }
    };

    // изменение сумм при ручном изменении кол-ва
    $(".handle-quantity").on('input', function(){
        let parent = $(this).closest(".t812__pricelist-item");
        let id = parent.attr('id');
        let count = CatalogComponent.init();
        let price = parent.find(".prod_price").text();
        let prodSum = Math.abs((count * price).toFixed(2));

/*        // изменение суммы по товару
        parent.find(".sum").text(prodSum);
        // изменение суммы корзины
        changeTotalSum($(this));
        //изменение кол-ва товара в базе
        var arr = {'id': id, 'count': count};
        changeSumInBd(arr);*/
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class = "tbcs">
    <div class="order__minus order__minus--large" tabindex="2" style="font-weight:100; margin: 0;">
        <span>-</span>
    </div>
    <div class="order__count order__count--large">
        <span>
            <input id="product_1" type="number" value="15" class="handle-quantity" style="width: 50px; text-align: center; outline: none; border: none; font-weight:100; font-size: 14px;">
                <div class="hidden js_qant"
                     data-available='40'
                     data-min_quantity='10'
                     data-step_quantity='10'
                ></div>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="order__plus order__plus--large" tabindex="1" style="font-weight:100; margin: 0;">
        <span>+</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Denis640Kb**, огромнейшее спасибо за ваш ответ, дельные замечания, суть понял, технически реализовал. выкладываю ниже, может кому-то пригодится. Основная суть ошибки заключалась в том, что инициализация событий была в двух местах и каждому обработчику этих событий доставались то одинаковые, то разные данные + конечно же все остальные замечания. Собрал всё в кучу, проработал по списку все замечания.

```
var CatalogComponent = {
productPage: false,
url: document.location.pathname,
basket: 'basket',
page: 'page',
count: 0,

init: function () {
    var $products = $('body');
    self = this;

    //устанавливаем начальное значение суммы и количества товара в корзине при открытии попапа с товаром в карточке товара
    $products.on('click', '.t754__content', function () {
        var str = $(this).find(".js-product-name").attr("field");

        var id = str.replace("li_title__", "");
        var parent = $products.find("#t754__product-" + id);
        var price = parent.find("div.js-product-price").text();
        var quant = parent.find(".handle-quantity").val();
        var summ = (price * quant).toFixed(2);
        var product_id = parent.find(".js-product-name").data('product-id');
        $('.tt_summ').html(summ).val();

        //вычисляем сколько уже в корзине этого товара
        inCartYet(product_id);
    });

    //реакция на нажатие + (и в корзине и в карточке)
    $products.on('click', '.order__plus', function () {
        //изменяется кол-во в инпуте
        self.changeCount($(this).parent().find('.handle-quantity'), true);
        if (getUrl() == CatalogComponent.page) {
            //изменяется сумма на странице
            changeSumInPage(this)
        }
        if (getUrl() == CatalogComponent.basket) {
            //изменяется сумма в корзине
            changeSumInBasket($(this));
        }
    });

    //реакция на нажатие - (и в корзине и в карточке)
    $products.on('click', '.order__minus', function () {
        //изменяется кол-во в инпуте
        self.changeCount($(this).parent().find('.handle-quantity'), false);
        if (getUrl() == CatalogComponent.page) {
            //изменяется сумма на странице
            changeSumInPage(this)
        }
        if (getUrl() == CatalogComponent.basket) {
            //изменяется сумма в корзине
            changeSumInBasket($(this));
        }
    });

    //изменения при ручном вводе
    $products.on('change', '.handle-quantity', function () {
        self.setCount($(this), $(this).val());
        if (getUrl() == CatalogComponent.page) {
            changeSumInPage(this, self.count);
        }
        if (getUrl() == CatalogComponent.basket) {
            let parent = $(this).closest(".t812__pricelist-item");
            let id = parent.attr('id');
            let count = self.count;
            let price = parent.find(".prod_price").text();
            let prodSum = Math.abs((count * price).toFixed(2));
            // изменение суммы по товару
            parent.find(".sum").text(prodSum);
            // изменение суммы корзины
            changeTotalSum($(this));
            //изменение кол-ва товара в базе
            var arr = {'id': id, 'count': count};
            changeSumInBd(arr);
        }
    });

    //добавление товара в корзину из карточки товара
    $products.on('click', '.order__basket', function () {
        var order = $(this).closest('.order'),
                productCount = order.find('.handle-quantity').val(),
                productId = order.data('product-id');
        if (productCount === undefined)
            productCount = order.find('.order__count span')[0].textContent;
        if (self.productPage) {
            productId = $('.product-card__title').data('product-id');
        }

        $.ajax({
            url: '/atb',
            method: "POST",
            data: {'product_id': productId, 'count': productCount},
            headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': getToken()},
            success: function (data) {
                if (data === 'Added to cart') {
                    var countCart = $('.header__basket-note')[0].textContent;
                    $('.header__basket-note')[0].textContent = +countCart + 1;
                    swal({
                        text: "В корзину добавлено " + productCount + " шт.",
                        className: "my_swal_ok",
                        timer: 800,
                    });
                    setTimeout(inCartYet, 800, productId);
                } else if (data === 'Add count product') {
                    swal({
                        text: "добавлено ещё " + productCount + " шт.",
                        className: "my_swal_ok",
                        timer: 600,
                    });
                    setTimeout(inCartYet, 600, productId);
                } else if (data === 'no relations') {
                    swal({
                        title: "",
                        text: 'Вы не можете добавлять в корзину товар этого Поставщика. Сначала вам надо заключить соглашение с ним',
                        icon: "success",
                        className: "my_swal_error",
                        timer: 2000,
                        position: "bottom-start",
                        timerProgressBar: true,
                    });
                }
            }
        });

    });

    if ($('#product-page').length > 0) {
        this.productPage = true;
    }
},

changeCount: function ($input, plus) {
    var count = parseInt($input.val());
    var maxCount = $input.parent().find('div.hidden').data('available') ? $input.parent().find('div.hidden').data('available') : ($input.parent().find('div.hidden').data('min_quantity')) * 10000;
    var minCount = $input.parent().find('div.hidden').data('min_quantity');
    var stepCount = $input.parent().find('div.hidden').data('step_quantity');

    if (plus) {
        if ((count + stepCount) <= maxCount) {
            count += stepCount;
        } else {
            count = maxCount;
        }
    } else {
        if (count == maxCount) {
            if ((count - minCount) % stepCount != 0) {
                count -= minCount;
                if (count < stepCount) {
                    count = stepCount;
                }
                count = Math.ceil(count / stepCount) * stepCount;
                if ((count + minCount) < minCount) {
                    count = minCount;
                } else {
                    if ((count + minCount) > maxCount) {
                        count = maxCount - minCount;
                        count = Math.floor(count / stepCount) * stepCount;
                    }
                    count += minCount;
                }
            }
            if (count == maxCount) {
                count -= stepCount;
            }
        } else {
            if ((count - stepCount) >= minCount) {
                count -= stepCount;
            } else {
                count = minCount;
            }
        }
    }

    this.setCount($input, count);
},

setCount: function ($input, count) {
    var maxCount = $input.parent().find('div.hidden').data('available') ? $input.parent().find('div.hidden').data('available') : ($input.parent().find('div.hidden').data('min_quantity')) * 10000;
    var minCount = $input.parent().find('div.hidden').data('min_quantity');
    var stepCount = $input.parent().find('div.hidden').data('step_quantity');

    if (count === undefined) {
        count = $input.val();
    }
    if (count === '') {
        count = minCount;
    }
    if (!$.isNumeric(count)) {
        count = minCount;
    }
    if (count > maxCount) {
        count = maxCount;
    } else if (count === 0) {
        count = minCount;
    } else if (count <= minCount) {
        count = minCount
    }
    count = parseInt(count);
    if ((count - minCount) % stepCount != 0 && count != maxCount) {
        count -= minCount;
        if (count < stepCount) {
            count = stepCount;
        }
        count = Math.ceil(count / stepCount) * stepCount;
        if ((count + minCount) < minCount) {
            count = minCount;
        } else {
            if ((count + minCount) > maxCount) {
                count = maxCount - minCount;
                count = Math.floor(count / stepCount) * stepCount;
            }
            count += minCount;
        }
    }
    this.count = parseInt(count);
    $input.val(parseInt(count));
},
};

    // изменение сумм при кликах на + и - в карточке товара
    function changeSumInPage(data, count = null) {
        var parent = $(data).closest(".t754__product-full");
        var price = parent.find("div.js-product-price").text();
        if (count) {
            var summ = (count * price).toFixed(2);
        } else {
            var quant = parent.find(".handle-quantity").val();
            var summ = (price * quant).toFixed(2);
        }
        $('.tt_summ').html(summ).val();
    }
    // изменение сумм при кликах на + и - в корзине
    function changeSumInBasket(data) {
        let parent = $(data).closest(".t812__pricelist-item");
        let id = parent.attr('id');
    //    let znak = Number( $(data).children().eq(0).text() + "1" );
    //    let step = parent.find('.hidden.js_qant').data('step_quantity'); // Получить шаг
        let min = parent.find('.hidden.js_qant').data('min_quantity'); // Получить минимальное значение
        let count = +$("#product_" + id).val();
    //    count += znak * step;
        if (count <= 0 || !count) {
            count = min;
        }
        let price = parent.find(".prod_price").text();
        let prodSum = Math.abs((count * price).toFixed(2));
        // изменение суммы товара в корзине
        parent.find(".sum").text(prodSum);
        // изменение суммы корзины
        changeTotalSum(data);
        //изменение кол-ва товара из корзины в базе
        arr = {'id': id, 'count': count};
        changeSumInBd(arr);
    }

    //изменение кол-ва товара в базе
    function changeSumInBd(arr) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/ccp',
            method: 'POST',
            data: arr,
            headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': getToken()},
        });
    }

    //изменение суммы корзины при кликах на + и -
    function changeTotalSum(data, del = null) {
        let parent = $(data).closest(".cart_js");
        let id = parent.attr('id').replace("cart_", '');
        let prods = parent.children('.t812__pricelist-item');
        let totalSum = 0;
        prods.each(function () {
            if ($(this).css('display') != 'none') {
                totalSum += +($(this).find(".sum").text());
            }
        });
        if (del > 0) {
            totalSum = totalSum - del;
        }
        $("#totalsumm_" + id).text((totalSum).toFixed(2));
        // изменение суммы до мин заказа + скрытие блока
        changeRest(data);
    }

    //изменение суммы, оставшейся до минимального заказа в корзине + скрытие блока
    function changeRest(data) {
        var rest = getRest(data);
        var val_rest = (getMinOrder(data) - getTotalSum(data)).toFixed(2);
        var id = getId(data);

        if (val_rest <= 0) {
            val_rest = 0;
            $("#fin_help_" + id).animate({height: 'hide'}, 500);
        } else {
            $("#fin_help_" + id).animate({height: 'show'}, 500);
        }
        rest.text(val_rest);
    }

    function getMinOrder(data) {
        var id = getId(data);
        var min_order = $("#min_order_" + id).text();
        return parseFloat(min_order);
    }

    //получение контекста, в котором хранится сумма, оставшаяся до минимального заказа
    function getRest(data) {
        let id = getId(data);
        let rest = $("#rest_" + id);
        return rest;
    }

    //получение общей суммы из корзины
    function getTotalSum(data) {
        let id = getId(data);
        let totalSum = $("#totalsumm_" + id).text();
        return parseFloat(totalSum);
    }

    //получение id заказа в корзине внутри которого был инициирован this
    function getId(data) {
        let parent = $(data).closest(".cart_js");
        let id = parent.attr('id').replace("cart_", '');
        return id;

    }

    //получение csfr-токена
    function getToken() {
        return $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
    }

    // проверяем, вызывается событие из корзины или из карточки товара
    function getUrl() {
        if ((CatalogComponent.url).indexOf('basket') >= 0) {
            return CatalogComponent.basket;
        } else {
            return CatalogComponent.page;
        }
    }

    function inCartYet(product_id) {
        var price = $('#price_' + product_id).attr('content');
        $.ajax({
            url: '/cib',
            method: "POST",
            cache: false,
            data: {'product_id': product_id},
            headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': getToken()},
            success: function (countInCart) {
                if (countInCart > 0) {
                    $('#js-text_in_cart_' + product_id).html("В <a href=\"/basket\">корзине</a> " + countInCart + ' шт. на сумму ' + (countInCart * price).toFixed(2) + 'грн.');
                    $('#js-in_cart_' + product_id).animate({"height": "show"}, 500);
                }
                countInCart = 0;
            },
        });
    }

    //удаление товара из корзины с удалением из БД
    $('.delete-order').on('click', function () {
        var id = $($(this).closest('span')).data('id');
        let parent = $(this).closest(".t812__pricelist-item");
        let sum = parseFloat(parent.find(".sum").text());
        let obj = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            url: '/dfb',
            method: 'POST',
            data: {'id': id},
            headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': getToken()},
            success: function (data) {
                if (data == 1) {
                    $("#" + id).animate({"height": "hide"}, 400);
                    changeTotalSum(obj, del = sum);
                }
            }
        });

        //если товар последний в корзине, то перезагрузим страницу
        let cart = $(this).closest(".cart_js");
        let prods = cart.children('.t812__pricelist-item');
        var n = -1;
        prods.each(function () {
            if ($(this).css('display') != 'none') {
                n++;
            }
        });
        if (n === 0) {
            setTimeout(window.location.reload.bind(window.location), 100);
        } 
        return false;
    });

    //отображение картинки товара в swal по клику в корзине
    $(".imgjs").on('click', function () {
        let img = $(this).attr("src");
        let alt = $(this).attr("alt");
        swal({
            text: alt,
            className: "my_swal_ok",
            icon: img,
            imageHeight: 900,
            imageAlt: alt,
    //        timer: 2000,
        });
    });
```